Installing Alpine on DC Roma Laptop II (RISC-V): How can I make an image from a "Mini Root Filesystem"?
I recently asked a question on Reddit about how to install Arch on my DC Roma Laptop II. One of the suggestions was to use Alpine instead because it has support for RISC-V. Looking at the downloads page there is indeed a RISC-V "Mini Root Filesystem" available for download. After downloading this I tried converting it into an iso using (similar to what I described in the Reddit thread):
mkisofs -o alpine_riscv.iso ~/Downloads/alpine-minirootfs-3.20.3-riscv64

And to copy it to the Micro SD card that I intend to boot from I ran:
sudo dd if=alpine_riscv.img of=/dev/sdb bs=64M conv=fsync oflag=direct status=progress

After trying to boot up the computer with the Micro SD inserted I just get a blank screen. I am not really sure what to do with a "Mini Root Filesystem" in order to actually build a correct image. (I am used to just flashing pre-built ISO files. I suspect I am doing something gravely wrong.) Is there some command line utility to help convert Mini Root Filesystems to ISO images that I can use to boot from?

Hm, you might have to have a specific kernel build with support for all the hardware in that laptop, or you might not have to have that. What's the way that the vendor of that laptop says you get Linux on that? It might just be easier to piggyback on their kernel and on their bootloader.

@MarcusMüller I don't believe the vendor has any support for installing Alpine Linux. Instead it comes pre-installed with a Ubuntu-like OS and also has a Micro SD card that has Debian installed on it. They do seem to have their own Linux kernel though. I just wanted to see if it was possible to get Alpine on this computer some how.

I should say, there is no official* support for installing Alpine Linux.


…to ISO images that I can use to boot from?

Those images aren't bootable because they're ISO files – it's more like they're bootable despite being ISO files.
A true ISO 9660 filesystem (such as the one you create with mkisofs) would have a boot header entirely different than the usual MBR or GPT – it would use the El Torito format, with a special mkisofs option for that (which works by embedding a whole separate "boot image" that might have its own filesystem!) – and then it would only be bootable as a CD/DVD.
Instead, the images you were writing to SD cards were either specifically prepared to become "hybrid ISO" images that have multiple overlapping headers (e.g. the same EFI System Partition being simultaneously referenced from GPT and El Torito), or weren't ISO 9660 images at all; indeed the term "ISO" is largely vestigial outside of x86 images.
(It is true that most "USB stick" images for x86 PCs are traditionally hybrid images that still have an ISO 9660 filesystem for burning to a CD, but an image that was meant to be purely written to SD/USB has no reason to have one – e.g. an ARM64 image meant for a Raspberry Pi's SD card has no traces of being an "ISO".)
So if you are not writing the image to a DVD, you should ignore mkisofs entirely and instead think of those images as a literal 1:1 copy of what you'd normally have on the system disk. That is, a GPT partition table, a regular FAT32 "EFI System Partition" (as far as I know, RISC-V uses UEFI?), a regular ext4 "Alpine rootfs" partition, and of course something like GRUB to make it bootable.
To create that, you can either:

create an XX GB empty file (using fallocate or other tools),
attach it using losetup -P,
partition it using fdisk,
create filesystems using mkfs.fat /dev/loop0p0 and mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p1,
mount onto /mnt, unpack the tarball, chroot, install a kernel (as I recall, Alpine's miniroot has no kernel), install GRUB or whatever bootloader RISC-V systems may use. You may need to use qemu's userspace emulation tools in order to chroot and run apk.

...or skip the 'image' and just partition & mkfs the actual SD card, as the result would be the same.

There's also another approach: if the laptop already runs Ubuntu, it would be possible to install another distribution from the inside. Untar the miniroot to /new; use the Debian SD card to move all the old contents (i.e. the Ubuntu [/mnt]/usr and such) to [/mnt]/old, and swap the Alpine miniroot from /new in their place; chroot and install an Alpine kernel¹; make sure the bootloader configuration is still valid.
¹ It should be possible to boot Alpine using an Ubuntu kernel as well, as long as the /lib/modules from Ubuntu is copied into the Alpine rootfs.

Thanks for the help! I got it to work using a hybrid of your second idea. I dded the Micro SD that came with Debian onto another Micro SD. I noticed in gparted it had stuff like boot uboot and rootfs. I then replaced the rootfs partition with the Alpine rootfs contents. Then it seemed to boot. Although I don't know the password to log in... I guess that is another question.
